# Django+heroku: django logs appear, app logs don't

Tags: python, django, logging, heroku

I read all the StackOverflow answers, all the blog posts on the subject, and tried everything twice, but I still can't get my Django app's log messsages to appear in the heroku log (Django's own messages do appear).

Can anyone please paste a full LOGGING config that works in heroku?

```
# views.py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def a_view(request):
    # ...
    logger.exception('error finding file')
    # ...
```

with:

```
# settings.py
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            "stream": sys.stdout
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "root": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
        },
        # last try :(
        "myapp": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
        },
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a configuration that worked for me (OP):

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            "stream": sys.stdout
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            'level': 'INFO',
        }
    }
}
```

The modification that made the difference is changing the level of all loggers, but before that I changed `"root"` to `""`, so that might have been needed too.

edit: removed "myapp" logger as it is captured by "" logger, resolved my double logging issue.